# How to determine the sample size for variance calculation in AB testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, sample-size

I am studying AB testing. I can understand that the sample size for AB testing would require the variance information. And many online calculators can provide sample size for each group in AB testing. My question is: to calculate the variance analytically, do we need a sample size also? How can we determine this size?

For example, assuming we have a click-through probability (P) from historical data,  the sampling variance can be calculated as P(1-P)/n. How can we determine this n value?

It is kinda like the problem of chicken or egg for me. Or do I have any misunderstanding about this issue?

Comment: If you've found the answer by Demetri helpful, please don't to forget to upvote and accept it - it seems a lot of effort went into it.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your notification. Sorry, I am new here. I will upvote and accept the answer after Demetri helps verify my follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider an AB test like an ANOVA but for logistic regression, you can use sample size equations for logistic regression to determine the sample size for your AB test.

The number of samples to detect an effect of size $\beta$ with $\gamma$ power is

$$ n = \dfrac{(z_{1-\alpha/2} + z_\gamma)^2}{(\beta\sigma_x)^2p(1-p)(1-\rho^2)} $$

$\sigma_x = \sqrt{f(1-f)}$ where $f$ is the fraction of people in your baseline variant.  $p$ is the marginal probability of a click (you can use historic click data here unless you think the variant will be much much different than baseline.  This isn't usually the case). $1-\rho^2$ is the variance inflation factor, but if you randomly assign the groups, this should not be important).  The $z$ are appropriate quantiles of a standard normal distribution.  $\beta$ is on the log odds scale and is the effect of the variant.  If you think the difference in probaility between baseline and variant is $\delta$, then $\beta = \log(\delta/(1-\delta))$.

More information can be found in [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461413523) book.

Comment: Hi Demetri, thank you for your answer. It seems that the sample size calculation doesn't require the variance in a sampling distribution of sample proportion. Could you verify this for me? (I am asking this because I saw many AB people calculated the variance before calculating the sample size using an arbitrary sample size for some unknown reason.)

Comment: I can't speak to what you have seen.  The AB testing framework fits nicely into a logistic regression framework, and so the sample size formula I have provided seems most appropriate. The equation above makes use of the variance of the marginal outcome (that is, the outcome without stratifying by variant), but I do not see the variance of the sampling distribution of the sample proportion being of much use.  I would encourage you to verify that this equation works by conducting a simple simulation.

Comment: Hi Demetri, thanks for your verification and suggestion!